# How to convert HTML output for pandas dataframes to LaTeX when using nbconvert?

Tags: pandas, ipython, jupyter

I am using the jupyter/ipython notebook in a class to do data treatment with pandas and write my report all in one document. I wanted to use nbconvert to convert my ipynb file to pdf afterwards. This works mostly fine, but the pandas dataframes which have a nice HTML representation do not get converted nicely via LaTeX.

```
ipython nbconvert --to pdf My_Report.ipynb
```

or

```
ipython nbconvert --to markdown My_Report.md
pandoc -i My_Report.md -o My_Report.pdf
```

If I want to get nicely formatted LaTeX/pdf tables, I need to do explicitly output LaTeX which does not give you a nice representation in the notebook:

```
from IPython.display import Latex
Latex(df.to_latex())
```

Is there a way to get both versions at the same time? HTML in  the notebook and clean Latex for the conversion?

Comment: This looks similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20685635/pandas-dataframe-as-latex-or-html-table-nbconvert

Comment: Yes indeed. I had a second look at the answers and the answer to my question was in the lower ones, so I upvoted that one :-). How can I retract my question?